# How to delete characters and append strings?

Tags: c#, string

I am adding a new record to XML file, first I'm querying all existing items and storing the count in an `int`

```
int number = query.count()
```

and then increment the number by 1.

```
number = number + 1;
```

Now I want to format this value in a string having `N00000000` format
and the number will occupy the last positions.

Pseudo code:

```
//declare the format string
sting format = "N00000000"

//calculate the length of number string
int length =number.ToString().Length();

// delete as many characters from right to left as the length of number string
???

// finally concatenate both strings with + operator
???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i = 123;
string n = "N" + i.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Comment: I went to the trouble of making my own extension method for this :( . Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

```
String output = "N" + String.Format ("00000000", length)
```

Alternatively if you change your formatstring to `"'N'00000000"` you can even use:

```
String output = String.Format (formatString, length)
```

Which means you can fully specify your output by changing your formatstring without having to change any code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built in `ToString` overload that takes a [custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx):

```
string result = "N" + number.ToString("00000000");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = number.ToString("N{0:0000000}");
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Here is a another one ...

```
result = String.Format("N{0:00000000}",number);
```